# E:Vyprvpn needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: networking, vpn, 15.10

I know similar topics have already been posted, but I seem unable to apply any of the solutions, since the faulty installation of the VyprVPN beta, which I downloaded from their website, is not allowing me to open Ubuntu Software Center or to install any new items. I just keep on getting the error "E:Vyprvpn needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it."

I tried manually deleting the entry from /var/lib/dpkg/status that reads:

```
Package: vyprvpn
Status: install reinstreq half-configured
Priority: optional
Section: net/non-free
Installed-Size: 15
Maintainer: Gregory Horejsi 
Architecture: amd64
Version: 0.0.1-55
Provides: vyprvpn
Depends: network-manager, network-manager-pptp, network-manager-openvpn, network-manager-vpnc
Description: VyprVPN for Linux - Provides a simple service and command line interface to manage NetworkManager based connections to VyprVPN
Homepage: http://www.goldenfrog.com/
```

But I get the following error:

```
Could not create a backup file while saving “/var/lib/dpkg/status”
```

Any help resolving this would be much appreciated. I am running Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Have you tried the technical support at the vendor's website?

Comment: `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq vyprvpn`

Comment: @CharlesGreen No I haven't. I assumed it wouldn't be very productive since it is a beta client, but you are right, I should contact them regarding the matter.

Comment: @A.B. Your command returned some errors and I still can't open the software center. [code]stop: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
dpkg: error processing package vyprvpn (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 vyprvpn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases the command

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq vyprvpn
```

is enough. In your case the problem derives from the pre-removal script:

> dpkg: error processing package vyprvpn (--remove): subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1 start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket

Delete the pre-removal script:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/vyprvpn*.prerm
```

Now remove the package again

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq vyprvpn
```

Comment: If there also an problem in the post-removal script, give me a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The error I am getting now is `rm: cannot remove ‘/var/lib/dpkg/info/vyprvpn*.prerm’: No such file or directory
`

Comment: Run `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq vyprvpn` again

Comment: Thanks, that worked now. I can open Ubuntu Software Center again.

Comment: Don't thank me **;)** Accept the answer with a click on the check mark at the left side of the answer.